# About these sets

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Some one can explain to me the meaning of these sets :

$C\left[[t_0,t_0+T]\times \mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\right]
$

$C^1\left[[t_0,t_0+T],\mathbb{R}\right]
$

I am very thankful in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of functional analysis, the symbols $C$ and $C^1$ indicate, respectively, the set of continuous functions and thr set of functions with first derivative continuous.

In the parentesis of this notation is indicated the domain and codomain of the functions.

So, as an example, the function $y=\sin(x+vt)$ with $t$ in the interval $[t_o,t_0+T]$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and real valued, is an element of the first set.